# Can write a Oracle function to scale oCPU ATP

Tags: oracle, function, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have been using ATP for transaction workload. But ATP limits 300 session per oCPU so can I write an Oracle function to adjust CPU when I receive a session alarm?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you meant a procedure or [Cloud Function](https://www.oracle.com/in/cloud/cloud-native/functions/#rc30p3), when you referred to Oracle function, but this should be possible.

ATP has APIs to update the instance, making a call to [UpdateAutonomousDatabase](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/database/20160918/AutonomousDatabase/UpdateAutonomousDatabase) from with the new oCPU value should scale it.

Here are some resources that I found which might help, although some modifications might be needed

[How do I scale an Autonomous Database?](https://sqlmaria.com/2019/10/22/how-do-i-scale-an-autonomous-database/)
[Automatic (Scheduled) Scaling for ADW and ATP](https://oc-blog.com/2018/09/15/automatic-scheduled-scaling-for-adw-and-atp/)